# How can I install windows while Ubuntu is already on my system?

Tags: dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 12.10 on my system and I want to install Windows 7. I tried it but Ubuntu was not found on the system anymore so I had to install Grub. When I installed the Grub menu on Ubuntu, Windows created a hard disk in NTFS file but when I rebooted, Windows didn't show up. I deleted all the Windows files. Now I want to re-install Windows 7 once again but I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: For installing Win7 after installing Ubuntu, see if [this answer helps](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281737/how-to-remove-ubuntu-partitions-and-use-them-to-install-windows/281817#281817)

Answer (score -1):

I have xp "installed" in a Virtual box. I like this much better than trying to dual boot. Windows is a "guest" of Ubuntu but it still can do everything it likes in its virtual box.